# Как из launch.json извлечь значения env для Python кода?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Необходимо из файла launch.json извлечь некоторые значения из configurations.env для дальнейшего использования этих значений в python коде. Не знаю, как обратиться через python к данному значению.

Пример launch.json:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не зная содержимого launch.json нельзя сказать ничего определенного.

Comment: Прочитать файл и получить из него данные. Посмотрите документацию на модуль JSON

Comment: @insolor, учёл ваше замечание и добавил фото с кодом! Для примера хотелось бы извлечь val1 значение из env.

Comment: @Kers, Благодарю вас за полезный комментарий! То есть для решения данной проблемы поможет использование модуля JSON?

Comment: Если запускаете через vscode, пробуйте `import os` `print(os.environ['val1']))`

Comment: @AspiringToBeAJune раз вы пытаетесь получить инфо из Json то логично использовать модуль JSON

Comment: @insolor, Ваше решение является ответом на мой вопрос!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @gil9red, Понял вас! В следующий раз учту это при необходимости демонстрации кода/ошибок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске через vscode ключи/значения из раздела "env" файла launch.json добавляются в [переменные окружения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B). Для доступа к переменным окружения из Python используйте объект [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), пример:

```
import os

print(os.environ['val1'])
```